# Print the current source node of the comment

Tags: nodes, forms, theming, comments

I wold like to have some clues to search. 
Out of the box Drupal let you see the original article or page when you write a comment and click *"preview"*. I search everywhere and I haven't a clue about how to fix the problem when I make a custom tpl for the coment-form.tpl.php I lost the part where I see the original source of the subject I'm posting. I just see the comment form. I think is not comment.tpl or comment-wrapper.tpl I also make a custom module but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node id for the comment is stored in:

```
$comment->nid
```

e.g, in the template, to print out the node, you could:

```
if (isset($comment->nid)) {
  print render(node_view(node_load($comment->nid)));
}
```

You could also add it as a template variable in preprocess function.

See [node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7) for more options

Comment: Right now I'm using this format in my template.php:
function THEME_preprocess_comment_form(&$variables) {

 $variables['form_id'] = render($variables['form']['form_id']);
 
 $variables['actions'] = render($variables['form']['actions']); 
 
}

Should I use this? $variables['current_article'] = render(node_view(node_load($variables['form']['#nid'])));

Comment: Possibly, but you'd need to print out that $var in your tpl file.